# Select on View return data in different order randomly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a strange result from a view, when I list the query below, is returning the same quantity of records but randomly in different order without having any order by inside.

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.[InvoiceDate] ) AS [RowId],
            i.InvoiceSummaryId AS IdKey

       FROM [rpt].[InvoiceView] i
      INNER JOIN PIT.Period p
         ON p.PeriodMonth = i.PeriodMonth 
        AND p.PeriodYear = i.PeriodYear
        and p.TenantId = i.TenantId

       LEFT JOIN [rpt].[InventoryView] s
         ON s.[InvoiceSummaryId] = i.[InvoiceSummaryId]
        and s.TenantId = i.TenantId 

    WHERE i.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-01'
      AND i.TenantId = 1
```

The issue is caused by the view [rpt].[InventoryView], if I remove the left join with the view, I always get the same result, but when I put it back, the result order is random. the reason I put left join is because on the view [rpt].[InventoryView], the column [InvoiceSummaryId] could be null.

Here the [rpt].[InventoryView] view code:

```
ALTER VIEW [rpt].[InventoryView]
AS
    SELECT  si.InvoiceSummaryId,
            si.TenantId,
            si.ServiceInventoryId,
            si.AccountId,
            si.AccountNumber,
            si.ServiceTypeId,
            si.ServiceTypeName AS ServiceType,
            si.PeriodId,
            si.ProviderId,
            si.ProviderName,
            pe.InvoiceDate,
            em.EmployeeId,

            ( CASE WHEN NULLIF(em.EmployeeFirstName, '') IS NULL
                   THEN ISNULL(NULLIF(RTRIM(em.EmployeeLastName), ''), '')
                   ELSE RTRIM(em.EmployeeFirstName) + ISNULL(', ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(em.EmployeeLastName), ''), '')
               END ) AS Employee,

            em.EmployeeStatusId,
            em.ManagerStatusId,
            em.EmployeeNumber,
            em.EmployeeEmail,
            em.ManagerId,
            em.ManagerFirstName,
            em.ManagerLastName,
            (CASE WHEN NULLIF(em.ManagerFirstName, '') IS NULL 
                  THEN ISNULL(NULLIF(RTRIM(em.ManagerLastName), ''), '') 
                  ELSE RTRIM(em.ManagerFirstName) + ISNULL(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(em.ManagerLastName), ''), '') 
              END) AS Manager, 

            em.ManagerNumber,
            org.OrganizationId,
            org.LevelId_1,
            org.LevelName_1,
            org.LevelId_2,
            org.LevelName_2,
            org.LevelId_3,
            org.LevelName_3,
            org.LevelId_4,
            org.LevelName_4,
            org.LevelId_5,
            org.LevelName_5,
            org.LevelId_6,
            org.LevelName_6,
            org.LevelId_7,
            org.LevelName_7,
            org.LevelId_8,
            org.LevelName_8,
            org.LevelId_9,
            org.LevelName_9,
            org.LevelId_10,
            org.LevelName_10,
            ha.EsnNumber,
            ha.Make,
            ha.Model,
            ha.Name AS HardwareName,
            ha.SerialNumber,
            ha.WarehouseName,
            co.Name AS [Contract],
            co.Cost AS ContractCost,
            sc.ServiceCategoryId,
            sc.Name AS ServiceCategory
       FROM pit.ServiceInventory AS si

      INNER JOIN pit.Period AS pe
         ON pe.PeriodId = si.PeriodId
        AND pe.TenantId = si.TenantId

       LEFT JOIN cimpl.ServiceType AS st
         ON st.ServiceTypeId = si.ServiceTypeId
        AND st.TenantId = si.TenantId

       LEFT JOIN cimpl.ServiceCategory AS sc
         ON sc.ServiceCategoryId = st.ServiceCategoryId
        AND sc.TenantId = si.TenantId

       LEFT JOIN pit.Employee AS em
         ON em.EmployeeIdKey = si.EmployeeIdKey

       LEFT JOIN pit.Organization AS org
         ON org.OrganizationIdKey = si.OrganizationIdKey

       LEFT JOIN pit.HardwareInventory AS ha
         ON ha.HardwareInventoryIdKey = si.HardwareInventoryIdKey

       LEFT JOIN pit.Contract AS co
         ON co.ContractIdKey = si.ContractIdKey;
```

Is there any configuration at the level of the server that makes this different? I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: if you don't want a "random" order then you need to use `ORDER BY`

Comment: ^^^ ... In the `select` from the view. Not inside the view just to be clear.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, yeah, of course, thanks for clarifying

Comment: You should take a look at this article about ordering. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Comment: The ordering is not *random*.  It is indeterminate.

Comment: Not a problem, I added a this line ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.[InvoiceDate] ) AS [RowId] in the beginning of the query, why is still randomly order?

Comment: @carlosm because that line doesn't order the result set, you need to add an `ORDER BY` at the end of your select statement. `SELECT somecolumns FROM yourView ORDER BY column`

Comment: `ORDER BY` is used for two purposes - to properly *define* the context for another operation (windowed functions, `TOP`, `FETCH`, etc) or to define the final presentation order. The only time when those two purposes may coincide is in the  `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the outermost query.

Comment: ok thank a lot to everybody

Answer (score 0):

You can always expect a random order if you don't use order by whether you are using a view or not.  There is no guarantee of order based on Pk or anything else. EVER.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is built based on SET Theory.

As per sets {1,2,3} is equals to {3,1,2}. So there is no guarantee that your statement returned in ORDER. But the extension languages like TSQL in MSSQLSERVER, PL-SQL in ORACLE are having some mechanisms to achieve the order i.e ORDER BY.